# Flutter firebase integration getting error: Failed to turn object into JSON

Tags: firebase, flutter

All of the sudden I am getting the following error when doing any firebase interaction (auth or firestore) in my flutter Android app.

```
E/StorageHelpers(15925): Failed to turn object into JSON
E/StorageHelpers(15925): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'org.json.JSONObject com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzm.zzbf()' on a null object reference
E/StorageHelpers(15925):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzz.zzi(Unknown Source:126)
E/StorageHelpers(15925):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzz.zzg(Unknown Source:3)
E/StorageHelpers(15925):    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.zza(Unknown Source:28)
E/StorageHelpers(15925):    at com.google.firebase.auth.zzm.zza(Unknown Source:3)
E/StorageHelpers(15925):    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzaw.zzaa(Unknown Source:27)
E/StorageHelpers(15925):    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzcy.zzal(Unknown Source:0)
E/StorageHelpers(15925):    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzcy.zza(Unknown Source:0)
E/StorageHelpers(15925):    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzdb.zzb(Unknown Source:42)
E/StorageHelpers(15925):    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzci.dispatchTransaction(Unknown Source:13)
E/StorageHelpers(15925):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_auth.zzb.onTransact(Unknown Source:22)
E/StorageHelpers(15925):    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:697
```

)

Here are my firebase dependencies:

- firebase_auth: "^0.5.3"
- cloud_firestore: "^0.7.0+2"

**Similar** unresolved questions:

https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1068

[Failed to turn object into JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50265988/failed-to-turn-object-into-json)

Comment: I had this issue recently, but it turned out only on the emulator. Zhe app run fine on my phone. Wiping the emulator fixed it for me.

Comment: Hi is this issue fixed ? i am faccing the same issue in some devices i cant able  to fix this

Comment: @AnilKumarGN I recommend trying the first answer here. If that does not work, try creating the flutter project again and just copy your dart files over. Make sure you also copy the dependencies from pubspec.yml. Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

I just faced the same problem as yours, I think that's the latest update of Firebase cause this.

In the beginning, I tried to do **[Build] > [Clean Project]**, and **[File] > [Invalidate caches/Restart]** in Android Studio, but still not working, and this error still occurred.

Finally **I fixed this, when I removed the app on my device, and re-install**, now everything works fine.

Here's the version I use in my gradle file:

- com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.1.0
- com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:16.0.0

Hope this can help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this, but unfortunately it didn't work. However, before doing this I was reverting some changes and going back to previous commits. At the end the app was not even booting so I created a brand new flutter project, copied my dart files over and re-configure all the plugins.